# How can I retrieve value from data id?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a selection with id `select id="accTypeSel"`. The option value is retrieved from the json file `jsonData.json`. What I want to do is, I want to display the branch selected in `div id="display"`. I had try it in below syntax but It's not working.

```
var $branchDetail=$('#accTypeSel option:selected').attr('data.accList-branch');
var $value=$branchDetail.val();
$('#display').html($value);
```

Selection from JSON.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Acc Type
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="accTypeSel"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="display"></div>
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            datatype:"json",
            async:true,
            url:'ref/jsonData.json',
            success:function(data){
                 for (var i=0;i<data.accList.length;i++)
            {
                var $option=$('<option />');
                $option.attr('value',data.accList[i].code,data.accList[i].branch);
                $option.text(data.accList[i].code+" ("+data.accList[i].branch+")");
                $('#accTypeSel').append($option);
            }
                var $branchDetail=$('#accTypeSel option:selected').attr('data.accList-branch');
                var $value=$branchDetail.val();
                $('#display').html($value);



            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

jsonData.json

```
{
    "accList":[
        {
            "code":"1234",
            "branch":"Branch1"
        },
        {
            "code":"4321",
            "branch":"Branch2"
        },
        {
            "code":"1111",
            "branch":"Branch3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: do you mind trying this `var $branchDetail=$('#accTypeSel option:selected')` and then `console.log( $branchDetail);` ??

Comment: It came out long messages. I cannot understand it

Comment: is it the option you want? if so, you can then use `var $branchDetail=$('#accTypeSel option:selected').val()`

Comment: Yes..this is really the option I want

Comment: Maybe we would understand it. Add it to the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following code might be what you want:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      datatype: "json",
      async: true,
      url: 'ref/jsonData.json',
      success: function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.accList.length; i++) {
          var $option = $('<option />');
          $option.attr('value', data.accList[i].code);
          $option.data('branch', data.accList[i].branch);
          $option.text(data.accList[i].code + " (" + data.accList[i].branch + ")");
          $('#accTypeSel').append($option);
        }

        $('#accTypeSel').on('change', function() {
          displayBranchDetail();
        })

        function displayBranchDetail() {
          var $branchDetail = $('#accTypeSel');
          var $value = $branchDetail.find(':selected').data('branch');
          $('#display').html($value);
        }
        displayBranchDetail();


      }
    });
  </script>
```

Here's a Plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/BCEoxminr4JyCIQBfZua?p=preview

Comment: How can I display BRANCH ONLY not the CODE

Comment: np. I just added a data attribute to the option that equals the branch value. And updated your selector to be able to target the selected  option.

Comment: I have another question, let say I want the displayBranchDetail() to be included to another js, how can I do that?

Comment: You can just move the function over over. It doesn't need to be in the ajax success function. I put it there to keep things simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to get the 'display' value. I started typing the solution but got distracted with another work. Anyhow I am posting it. I hope it will give you more idea.

```js
var ajaxResponse = '{'+
    '"accList":['+
        '{'+
            '"code":"1234",'+
            '"branch":"Branch1"'+
        '},'+
        '{'+
            '"code":"4321",'+
            '"branch":"Branch2"'+
        '},'+
        '{'+
            '"code":"1111",'+
            '"branch":"Branch3"'+
        '}'+
    ']'+
'}';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(ajaxResponse);

var appendData = '';

$.each(jsonObj.accList, function(i, val){
        appendData += 
          '<option value='+val.code+' data-branch='+val.branch+'>' + 
          val.code + " (" + val.branch + ")" + '</option>';
  });

var accTypeSel = $('#accTypeSel');
accTypeSel.append(appendData);


accTypeSel.on('change', function(){
  $('#display').text(accTypeSel.find(':selected').data('branch'));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Acc Type
            </td>
            <td>
                <select id="accTypeSel"></select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="display"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```